# What is linear allocation?

Tags: android, allocation, android-multidex

When I read https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html to understand what and how to work with multidex, I don't understand the meaning of `linearalloc`:

> When running on versions prior to Android 5.0 (API level 21), using multidex is not enough to work around the linearalloc limit (issue 78035). This limit was increased in Android 4.0 (API level 14), but that did not solve it completely. And on versions lower than Android 4.0, you might reach the linearalloc limit before reaching the DEX index limit. So if you are targeting API levels lower than 14, test thoroughly on those versions of the platform, because your app might have issues at startup or when particular groups of classes are loaded.

Trying to search this term, I know the linearalloc is **linear allocation**. However, I still wonder these things:

1. What is the linear allocation exactly?
2. How many kind of allocations are there and how they are different from linear location?
3. Some example of using linear allocation.

Thanks for advises.